# Story set on an island?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources

I'm writing an urban fantasy and want to set it on an island. I'm not sure about how big it should be nor other details about the island.

I've done some research, but can't find much about the history of islands (e.g., how to figure out who would own it etc).

Can anyone point me in the right direction: where should I start and what/how much I need to know before putting pen to paper?

Comment: What have you uncovered through research so far?

Comment: US has a number of islands that you might be able to use for inspiration.  Ranging from Hawaii to Puerto Rico to Guam, or how about Bermuda?

Comment: Very wealthy people used to purchase entire islands in places like the "Thousand Islands" between Canada and the US for estates. Going the other way, the US Marines invaded and occupied Hispaniola in the early 20th century as part of the "Grand Strategy" of covering the approaches to the Panama Canal.

Comment: Also, there is an apparent legal loop hole which basically states: "you can claim any non-inhabited island as your own territory simply by living on it for an entire year (without assistance from the outside world in any which way)". I'm not sure if it is still a thing, but there was definitely a book written about it.

Comment: This question could use some additional details on setting. For example, can you define urban fantasy? To me that means vampires. Also, are you looking for a city island (Manhattan, Singapore), or a mid-sized island with a big city, (Taiwan or Long Island), or a small-ish island that also has a city, (Panay or Puerto Rico).

Comment: Well, if it's an urban fantasy (and based in the US), you're pretty much limited to Manhattan, Miami Beach, and a few others.  All the other islands I can think of have only limited urban areas on them, if there are any at all.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for resources [Island Cities and Urban Archipelagoes](http://www.islandcities.org/) might be interesting website worth trying. They deal with the following:

> Island Cities and Urban Archipelagos.
>
> Island Cities and Urban Archipelagos (ICUA) is an urban island studies
>   research network under the Island Dynamics organisation. ICUA promotes
>   research at the intersection of island studies and urban studies,
>   concerning the culture, economy, politics, planning, environment, and
>   design of urban areas based on islands worldwide. ICUA investigates
>   what island cities can tell us about broader wider development
>   processes and contributes to broadening the island studies research
>   field.

This might be heavier duty than you are looking for, but it could be somewhere to give you hints on what to look for in other reference resources.

If you prefer to stroll nonchalantly through some interesting and exotic island cities, National Geographic offers this list of their top ten [island cities](http://www.nationalgeographic.com/travel/top-10/island-cities/)

There is [City Island, Bronx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Island,_Bronx) which came as a surprise.

> City Island is located at the extreme western end of Long Island Sound,[2](http://www.nationalgeographic.com/travel/top-10/island-cities/) south of Pelham Bay and east of Eastchester Bay. The body of water between City Island and the even smaller (and uninhabited) Hart Island to the east is known as City Island Harbor. The small island adjacent to the northeast is High Island. The Stepping Stones Light, marking the main shipping channel into New York, is off the southern tip of the island, near the Long Island shore. It is part of the Pelham Islands, a group of islands once belonging to Thomas Pell.

Also, worthy of consideration are [Manhattan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan) and [Hong Kong Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Island).

These may be useful starting points for further research.

Answer (score 0):

Many islands are semi-autonomous dependencies of other nations. Reading the nation by nation profiles in the World Almanac is a good way to get familiar with them.